# Move azure VPN Gateway between two azure subscriptions

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machine, log-shipping

I want to move my two SQL VM which is under Log Shipping.
How can i move these VM to another azure subscription?
What things to be considered before moving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have SQL VM, but many documents have show us how to move the SQL VM to another Azure Subscription.

Firstly, SQL VM is also Azure resource, about move Azure resources, we should first learn from this Azure doucment: [Move resources to a new resource group or subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription).

Secondly, about how to move Azure VMs, here're many document may can help you:

1. [How to Migrate an Azure VM from One Subscription to Another](https://www.cloudconstruct.com/blog/migrating-an-azure-vm-from-one-subscription-to-another).
2. [How to manually move Azure VMs to another subscription](https://rlevchenko.com/2017/02/13/totd-how-to-manually-move-azure-vms-to-another-subscription/)

The easiest way you can try is: Service Overivew page--> `Move`--> `move to another subscription` on Portal:
[image]

Hope this helps.